# Array to string conversion while ajax call from javascript

Tags: php, json, ajax, jqgrid

here i want to fill jqgrid with my data so i have made ajax call to retrive data from mysql database . now i want to sent data from php to javascript ajax call but it gives me error like Array to string conversion in line no 25

getGrid.php

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    #$q = intval($_GET['q']);
    // include('conn/conn.php');

    $con = mysqli_connect('demoexample','root','','example'); 
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"example");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbldummy "; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
    $cat= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

     $name = $cat['name'];
     $sdate = $cat['sdate'];
     $stock = $cat['stock'];
     $ship = $cat['ship'];
     echo $name;
     echo $sdate;
     echo $stock;
     echo $ship;

   //error ->  echo $cat;
     echo jason_encode($cat);
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

jqgrid.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

         $.ajax({
        url: 'getGridData.php',
        type: 'POST',
       // data: ({name:name,sdate:sdate,stock:stock,ship:ship}),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: put error in here pls

Comment: jason_encode -> json_encode
Also, share your line number 25. Is this your entire code?

Comment: thanks @AkshayKhetrapal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you must use **json_encode** instead of **jason_encode** :)

And in this part of code

```
echo $name;
echo $sdate;
echo $stock;
echo $ship;

echo jason_encode($cat);
```

Use only

```
echo json_encode($cat);
```

After this, you can get fields of JSON in jQuery like

```
 cat = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(cat.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
$rows= array();
while($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $cat;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```